# IO filecannot access file in use

Tags: c#, io

Hi guys im busy writting a small console app that will pick up textfiles and mail them, but after mailing them the mailed textfile must be moved to a backup folder file... the problem is i get this error when i try Delete the file, but i know the file is not in use by me.

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Files\Configs\Errorlog.txt' because it is being used by another process.

I have used two methods file.move and file.copy then attempt to delete it still doesnt work i get the same error please assist

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("******");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("*********");
            mail.To.Add(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailReceiver"]);
            mail.Subject = "Test HHjhihH- Mail";
            mail.Body = "TestMail";

            string folder = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConfigPath"];

            try
            {
                string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");

                foreach (var txtfile in txtfiles)  //FileInfo file in Files )
                {
                    if (!File.Exists("ConfigPath"))//txtfile.Length != 0)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtfile));

                        Console.WriteLine("sending Config File....");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No files in the directory");

                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Path" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConfigPath"] + ",does not exist");
                return;
            }

            SmtpServer.Port = ****;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");

        }

        {



            string fileName = string.Empty;
            fileName = "Errorlog.txt";
            string sourceFile = @"C:\Files\Configs\" + fileName;
            string destinationFile = @"C:\Files\BackupConfigs\" + fileName;

            // To move a file or folder to a new location:

            **//error PROBLEM OCCRURS HERE**

            File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
       // copies the file but wont delete original file

            File.Delete(@"C:\Files\Configs\Errorlog.txt");

        // when i use File.move(sourceFile, destinationFile); i get same error


        }}
```

Comment: I'm sure the file is in use by you. You have to use a using when writing to a file or places where you access it with a IDisposeble object. BTW you realy need to clean up your code, it is realy messy and I see many bugs as result of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        SmtpServer.Port = ****;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail); 
        Mail.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");
```

After sending the mail i used Mail.dispose() it solved the problem i could then delete the file after sending it.
THANKS for your input guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the result of `new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtfile)` to a variable.

```
var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(txtfile);
```

After you have sent the mail, you must dispose the attachment:

```
attachment.Dispose();
```

It's keeping the file open.

Comment: yeah your right its keeping the attachment open i tried to use attachment.dispose didnt work the mail came back with no attachment, i used Mail.dispose();

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt")` delivers the pure filename.
So either you take an absolute filename, or make sure, that the file is located within the executing directory (debug, release, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a using clause everytime you try to work with file Access. If you don't, the file is in use in the Background after you have run your application once!